# Can't remove Youtube icon from sound indicator

Tags: unity, youtube, indicator-sound

I've tried to remove YouTube player from sounds menu in Ubuntu 13.10 but it doesn't worked.

I've done all these things from [this webupd8 site](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/05/how-to-quickly-remove-media-players.html).

I've already added to blacklisted player but it still shows in sound menu

> gsettings get com.canonical.indicator.sound interested-media-players:['YouTubeyoutubecom.desktop', 'rhythmbox.desktop']

Also I have been tried dconf tools but it still results the same.

dconf settings here:
[image: http://i59.tinypic.com/34etcuw.png]

Comment: Did you already try to **remove** `youTubeyoutbecom.desktop` from dconf settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, as Takkat said, remove the `['YouTubeyoutubecom.desktop']` from `com.canonical.indicator.sound interested-media-players`

Using some shell script:

```bsh
#!/bin/sh

// Get current value
val=$(gsettings get com.canonical.indicator.sound interested-media-players)

// Remove youtube
new_val=$(echo $val | sed -e "s/YouTubeyoutubecom.desktop//g")

// Set to the new expected value
gsettings set com.canonical.indicator.sound interested-media-players $new_val
exit 0
```

Or simply using dconf-editor...

Comment: thanks all <3 ive fixed that by using removing youtube from indicated players